# Best way to enter time in an optional 12 hr format?

Tags: usability, buttons, time

What's the best way for entering time in a 12-hour format?

1. It's easier to select from a radio button AM / PM but since this field is optional, what if they decided not to fill it out, they cannot unselect the radio button.
2. Here they're able to unselect AM/PM but defaulting to 'Select' but it's not as fast as just tapping a radio button.

[image]

Which is better? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: What do think about a switch with 2 label on each side (Am - Pm)

Comment: But I cannot unselect AM/PM if that's the case? @Core972 It must be either side..

Comment: Usually the AM option is selected by default.

Comment: You mention that the AM/PM is optional. If a user doesn't select AM or PM, does that mean that the time is in 24-hour format?

Answer (score 2):

**I like the radio buttons in that the information is not hidden.** 
As an European, who hardly use AM/PM, I would try to look for the other numbers and make a mess before realizing that I just had to choose AM/PM.
By seeing the options I get **clear expectations** and my mind set to the AM/PM model.

Comment: I didn't realize that AM/PM was not really a thing in Europe. Is that all of Europe (i.e. EU) in general or in specific regions?

Comment: From Wikipedia: The 24-hour clock enjoys broad everyday usage in most non-English speaking countries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country

Comment: Yeah, I currently live in Norway, have lived in The Netherlands, Spain and UK and for what I know most people use the 24h one.

Answer (score 2):

Showing the user information straightforward is incredibly effective. Less than 4 options show a radio fieldset.

When you have less than 4 items to display anywhere it almost always is a better idea to just show them to the user as in the case of radio buttons.

When you have several amounts to show then a dreaded dropdown option would suffice but for usability sake make the most used option a default preset so the user doesn't have to dig though massive amounts of data.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little bit more? It is a little bit difficult to understand the second part of your answer.

Comment: Pick an option to be preset either AM or PM. This way the user knows these can be active via the radio options. A user would know they can toggle. If its in a dropdown also preset a value instead of select as it would help them know that is something to interact with. I believe AM/PM a radio is pretty straightforward. No hidden values in a dropdown unless you have many other options.